# MongoDB query works in compass, but not in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-compass

I've a collection, roughly 100M documents. When I'm trying out this aggregation in compass:

```
aggregate([
            {
                '$match': {
                    'type': 'myType'
                }
            }, {
                '$group': {
                    '_id': '$name'
                }
            }, {
                '$limit': 10
            }]
```

, compass is coming back with some results fairly quickly.

Now, I want to use this aggregation within my python app, which translates than to something like:

```
        response = await request.app.db[MY_COLLECTION].aggregate([
            {
                '$match': {
                    'type': 'myType'
                }
            }, {
                '$group': {
                    '_id': '$name'
                }
            }, {
                '$limit': 10
            }
        ]).to_list(length=None)
```

, but apparently nothing really happens. Maybe after a long-ish waiting time, but nowhere near to what I can see when querying through compass.

*EDIT*

I've indices for `type`, `name` and for both of them as a compound index.

Comment: By default, `Compass` will `"$sample"` and `"$limit"` the collection to improve response time.  If you increase the `Compass` defaults, does the response time approach the `pymongo` time.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess, since I've already indexed my fields, I need to try out another data model. Maybe by mapping these values into a different collection.